# Faster way to retrieve remote SMS WMI Query in PowerShell

Tags: sms, remote-access, wmi-query, sccm

I'm trying to execute an SMS WMI query (now 2012, formerly 2007 with VBS) and it's sometimes taking up to 20 minutes (overseas) and 5-10 minutes (system is downstairs) when using the Get-WMIObject command. I know how to make a faster call in VBS:

```
        lLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")

        gService = lLocator.ConnectServer(Form1.strSQLServer, "root/sms/site_" & Form1.strSiteCode)

        'Query for Distribution Points and populate drop down list
        colItems = gService.ExecQuery("select PackageID, SourceNALPath from SMS_PackageStatusDistPointsSummarizer where PackageID='" & listBootImage.SelectedItem.ID & "'")
        For Each objItems In colItems
            ListDistPoint.Items.Add(UCase(Mid(objItems.SourceNALPath, InStr(objItems.SourceNALPath, "\"))))
            If InStr(objItems.SourceNALPath, Mid(Form1.strSQLServer, 1, (InStr(Form1.strSQLServer, ".") - 1))) Then
                ListDistPoint.SelectedIndex = ListDistPoint.Items.Count - 1
            End If
        Next
```

And in PS this is the call I'm making:

```
invoke-command {Get-WmiObject -namespace root\sms\site_<sitecode> -class SMS_PackageStatusDistPointsSummarizer -computername '<compname>' -property "PackageID","SourceNALPath" | where {$_.PackageID -eq '<pkgname>'} |Select PackageID, SourceNALPath}
```

or this:

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace root\sms\site_<sitecode> -class SMS_PackageStatusDistPointsSummarizer -computername '<compname>' -property "PackageID","SourceNALPath" | where {$_.PackageID -eq '<pkgname>'} |Select PackageID, SourceNALPath
```

and both of those are the same speed. Is there a better, ideal way to do the same thing like in the VB script (remote connect, retrieve info, then come back)? The VB script is noticeably faster. The hardware running the SCCM 2012 server is better, so I don't believe the speed is related to server performance. Also both databases contain the same sites, systems, etc.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace root\sms\site_$sitecode `
              -computername "$compname" `
              -query "select PackageID, SourceNALPath from SMS_PackageStatusDistPointsSummarizer where PackageID='$pkgname'"
```

With your other powershell statements, you're querying for *everything* and then filtering locally. With the WMI query you're running in the VBS, the querying is done on the *server* side. There's less data to process, and it's done more efficiently.